# Climbing at the Skytop area of the Gunks

Tags: rock-climbing, access-rights

The Skytop area at the [Gunks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shawangunk_Ridge) has a number of stellar climbs including [Foops (5.11)](https://www.mountainproject.com/v/foops/106364825) and [Super Crack (5.12+)](https://www.mountainproject.com/v/super-crack/111251312). From what I can piece together, climbing there [requires a guide](http://www.mohonkmountainguides.com/logistics.html) and buying a meal/pass at the resort. Despite the ridiculousness of paying over $500 to be escorted by a guide, is it possible to hire a guide who will sit back and just let my partner and I climb the routes we want? As I was not strong enough to climb Super Crack back in the days before requiring a guide, if we are in over our heads are the guides strong enough to retrieve our gear?

Answer (score 1):

I read the "Rock Climbing at Sky Top - Rates and Policies" and the informations on [TheCrag](https://www.thecrag.com/climbing/united-states/shawangunks) about this area. As TheCrag states:

> Sky Top has many classic routes, and was closed for over ten years by the landowner (the Mohonk Mountain House, an exclusive and expensive resort). As of April 2007 climbing is LEGAL at Sky Top once again - IF, and only if, you are there as a client of their only approved guide service, Alpine Endeavors.

I assume that the expensive rates are exist to keep the climbs exclusive to the customers of Mohonk Mountain House. As this is private land there is nothing you can do, besides trespassing of course.

Comment: I thought I was clear in my question that I know that a guide is required. What I wanted to know was how overbearing the guides are.

Comment: Oh, yes ... well just ask Alpine Endeavors.

Comment: I don't generally trust opinions from people trying to sell me stuff. I would much rather trust opinions/experiences of the people who bought the stuff or better yet know some of the guides.

Comment: Good luck. I hope someone is able to answer your question on stackexchange.